# What is equivalent of MATLAB's fread with skip parameter in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, file

I wonder how can I implement MATLAB

```
fread(fileID,sizeA,precision,skip)
```

in Python ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)). There are many advices how to deal with it in case of

```
fread(fileID,sizeA,precision)
```

but I need the `skip` parameter. So I want to obtain some

```
def fread(fileID,sizeA,precision,skip):
    # some code which do the same thing as matlab fread(fileID,sizeA,precision,skip)
    pass
```

How can it be implemented without symbol-wise reading?

Comment: Can you give more details of what you want to do?

Comment: @lhoupert I updated the question, hope it's clear now

Comment: Have you check these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048921/how-to-use-function-like-matlab-fread-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146031/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fread-from-matlab-in-python)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of 'fread' from Matlab in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146031/what-is-the-equivalent-of-fread-from-matlab-in-python)

Comment: @llhoupert No, as I said it is all examples without implementing of `skip` parameter. It's crucial for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to parse complex binary structures, including pad bytes. For instance, copying the Matlab doc, if you want to read a file of 2 short ints followed by 2 pad bytes:

```
import struct
fmt = "=hhxx" #native endianness and no alignment (=), two shorts (h), two pad bytes (x)
data = [x for x in struct.iter_unpack(fmt, open("nine.bin", "rb").read())]
## [(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8)]
```

Note that the output of `struct.iter_unpack`, and the other unpack methods, is a tuple.

Comment: it raises a error `iterative unpacking requires a buffer of a multiple of 6 bytes`

Comment: @Nourless - you need to create the file like in the MATLAB docs. `fwrite(fileID,[1:9],'uint16');` creates a file of exactly 18 bytes.